# Increment an integer Map value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Given a Map or MutableMap:

```kotlin
val scores: MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf(
        "some person" to 0,
        "some other person" to 0,
        "you" to 0,
        "me" to 0
)
```

I am unable to increment these as I would in Python, and I'm not sure what the proper way to do it is, or if it is even possible.

```kotlin
fun test() {
    scores["you"] += 2
}
```

This gives the error:

```
Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'scores["you"].plusAssign(2)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'scores["you"]'.
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

The top answer contains false information. It does not always look for the `plusAssign` operator, and you **can** use indexing along with `+=` in some cases.

According to the [**actual doc**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#assignments), it first looks for `plusAssign`, and then uses it if there is no `plus` operator function available, if there is no `plusAssign` available, it tries to generate code like: `a = a + b`.

If you were to use an `ArrayList`, it can work, for example:

```kotlin
val arr = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
arr[0] += 4  // arr[0] = arr[0] + 4 -> arr.set(0, arr.get(0) + 4)
arr // 5, 2, 3, 4
```

The only problem is that `map[key]` returns a `null` reference when the key does not map to a value in the map. So here's another way of doing it, without a dot qualified call:

```kotlin
val map = hashMapOf(1 to 2, 3 to 4)
// map += 1 to map[1]!! + 2 // If you are sure about the key 
map += 1 to ((map[1] ?: 0) + 2) // map.put(1, (map.get(1) ?: 0) + 2)
map // { 1: 4, 3: 4 }
```

You don't even need to use the `merge` method, simply add an extension function:

```kotlin
operator fun Int?.plus(other: Int) = this?.plus(other) ?: other
fun main() {
    val map = hashMapOf(1 to 2, 3 to 4)
    map[1] += 2 // map[1] = map[1] + 2 -> map.put(1, map.get(1).plus(2))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` operator is a shorthand operator for the `plusAssign` function ([doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-assign.html)), and is used for adding or replacing entries to a mutable map or collection, as specified by the Kotlin [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/map-operations.html#map-write-operations) for map operations

> You can also add new entries to maps using the shorthand operator
> form. There are two ways:
>
> - `plusAssign` (+=) operator.
> - the `[]` operator alias for `set()`.

When you use `scores["you"] += 2`, since `+=` is a shorthand operator for `plusAssign`, and `scores["you"]` can return a nullable value (as can any *get* operation on a map), you get the compilation error

```
Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'scores["you"].plusAssign(2)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'scores["you"]'.
```

For your use-case, you can better use the `merge` method ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)) on the map as below

```
scores.merge("you", 2, Int::plus)
```

Do note that `merge` would add an entry to the map even if the key is absent in the map. In case you want to increment the value for the key only if it's present in the map, you can use the `computeIfPresent` method ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)) as below

```
scores.computeIfPresent("you"){ _, v -> v + 2 }
```

Comment: It gets expanded to `scores["you"] = scores["you"] + 2` but since `scores["you"]` can be null so you can't add `Int?`. Your answer didn't address this.

Comment: @Deadbeef I had added that in my initial answer, but I felt it was evident in the error message so removed that. I'll add that back.

Comment: And @Deadbeef it doesn't get expanded to `scores["you"] = scores["you"] + 2`. But to `scores["you"].plusAssign(2)`. `+=` is a shorthand operator to that.

Comment: I have my posted my own answer to clarify. Your link to the doc is misleading.